# Applying Linq to a DbSet inside DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have a model called `Item` which looks like this:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateArchived { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Alias { get; set; }
```

It has been included in the DbContext...

```
public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Whenever I want to select all items from the database, I want to include only items where `Archived == null` and sorted by `Alias`.

Is there a way to set up EF to do this when the DbSet is called (eg. on the DbContext)?

For example, if I call db.Items in a controller, I always want these options applied without having to state them explicitly.

My current way to do this is to rename the DbSet with prefix "All" and add a function with these options applied (function uses DbSet's original name so that scaffold controllers and pages use the customized query without requiring any changes):

```
public DbSet<Item> AllItems { get; set; }
public IQueryable<Item> Items
{
    get { return AllItems.Where(item => item.Archived == null).OrderBy(item  => item.Alias); }
}
```

But something about this method feels hackish/wrong. Is this a fine way to do it? How should this typically done?

Comment: I don't think it's hack-ish or wrong. What if you need all of the items too for some reason?

Comment: @I agree with @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey. It seems perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I've had similiar problem once and I created a database view to present my data with all neccessary limitations. View can have the same fields as a table, but not required to. Then you create another DbSet item, e.g. `DbSet<ItemView>`, which in the database coresponds to view instead of table. Inside of this view you declare where statement as you wish. If properties are the same, you can also create the same ancestor for both classes (e.g. `Item` and `ItemView` both inherit from `ItemBase`).

I've had this done on MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I generally avoid accessing DbSet's directly and enforce the idea by hiding the context behind an interface. Then I only access repository methods from the interface. This hides the DbSets from intelli-sense when using it in your client code if you'd prefer client code doesn't have access to the table collections (and want to steer them to some filtered subset of data).

```
public interface IDataContext : IDisposable
{
    void SaveChanges();
    IQueryable<Item> GetItems();
}

public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    public DataContext(string connectionStringName) : base(connectionStringName) { }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Item> GetItems()
    {
        return Items.Where(item => item.Archived == null).OrderBy(item  => item.Alias); 
    }
}

using (IDataContext context = new DataContext("myConnection"))
{
    var items = context.GetItems();
}
```